# Issues calling Objective-C API from Swift with NSArrays and NSDictionaries

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsarray, nsdictionary

I am trying to convert the following line of code from Objective-C to Swift:

```
- (void)updateContentForSpineIndex:(NSUInteger)currentSpineIndex
{
    NSString *contentFile = self.contentModel.manifest[self.contentModel.spine[currentSpineIndex]][@"href"];
```

Here is what I have converted it to:

```
func updateContentForSpineIndex(currentSpineIndex: Int)
{

    let contentFile = NSString(self.contentModel.manifest(self.contentModel.spine(currentSpineIndex))("href"))
```

I'm getting an error, '(Int) -> $T7' is not identical to '[AnyObject]'

I've tried changing the types around, casting, and everything my newbie brain can think of but I keep getting similar errors.  The contentModel object is being created from the following Objective-C code if this helps:

```
@interface KFEpubContentModel : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) KFEpubKitBookType bookType;
@property (nonatomic) KFEpubKitBookEncryption bookEncryption;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *metaData;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *coverPath;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *manifest;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *spine;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *guide;

@end
```

Comment: can you elaborate a bit on what types do dictionaries and arrays contain? so i can write swift code. particularly, what is inside spine array

Comment: Here is what the debugger has:  _spine = (NSArray *) @"386 objects", [0] = (_NSCFString *) @"ncx", [0] (_NSCFString *).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this. i assumed manifest dictionary contains dictionaries of string-string key-values

```
class KFEpubContentModel {
    var manifest: Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, String>>?
    var spine: Array<String>?
}

var contentModel = KFEpubContentModel()
func updateContentForSpineIndex(currentSpineIndex: Int) {
    if let s = contentModel.spine {
        let currentSpine = s[currentSpineIndex]
        if let m = contentModel.manifest {
            let currentManifest = contentModel.manifest?[currentSpine]
            if let cm = currentManifest {
                let contentFile = cm["href"]
                if let cf = contentFile {
                    //do stuff
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```